# Rounded tableview header swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, header, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I am trying to add a rounded tableview header on top of a tableview. Its top is below an image:

[image]

so my idea was to draw a shaped view and add this view as a header.
But from the solutions I saw, all I was able to was this kind of shape:

[image]

My question is: how to have this view without the extra hight? So no hight below the corners.
Any other way to have achieve design is also good.

my code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500))
containerView.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView


let headerView = UIView()

let frame2 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 190, width: 300, height: 40)
headerView.clipsToBounds = true

headerView.backgroundColor = .red
headerView.frame = frame2

headerView.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 40)
containerView.addSubview(headerView)

extension UIView {

func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500))
containerView.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView


let headerView = UIView()
let frame2 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 190, width: 300, height: 22)
headerView.clipsToBounds = true

headerView.backgroundColor = .red
headerView.frame = frame2
draw(shapeView: headerView)
containerView.addSubview(headerView)

func draw(shapeView:UIView) {
    let path = headerView.headerBezierPath(hight: headerView.frame.height).cgPath
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = path
    shapeView.layer.mask = shape
}

extension UIView {
    func headerBezierPath(hight:CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
        let cardRadius = CGFloat(hight)
        let viewSize = self.bounds.size
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: 0))
    
        // top line
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width - cardRadius, y: 0))

        // top-right corner arc
        path.addArc(withCenter: 
        CGPoint(x: viewSize.width - cardRadius, y: cardRadius),
        radius: cardRadius,
        startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 3 / 2),
        endAngle: CGFloat(0),
        clockwise: true)

        // bottom line
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cardRadius))
    
        // top-left corner arc
       path.addArc(
          withCenter: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: cardRadius),
      radius: cardRadius,
      startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi),
      endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 3),
      clockwise: true
        )
    
        // close path join to origin
        path.close()
        // Set the background color of the view
        UIColor.gray.set()
        path.fill()
    
        return path
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use this View Extension

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

use of extension:

```
viewPopupCard.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 18)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your solution gives the same result as what my problem was initially:  the view has rounded corners at the top so that's ok, but it also has some extra hight below the corners, and that's what I was trying to remove. I found a solution tho, check out the other answer for the view without hight.